# Mysql MAMP Pro very very slow

Tags: mysql, mamp, mamp-pro

I was previously using Apache & PHP that come with OSX, and installed separately mysql 5.6.24. my app was running pretty good.

I then changed my laptop and decided to start using MAMP Pro that comes with mysql 5.6.35, and was surprised to see that some queries that used to be executed in 1.2s now run in average 5s :(
I have contacted the MAMP Pro support but wasn't able to solve the problem!
Did anyone experience this extreme slowness?

Thanks

Comment: no one had faced this problem?? :(

Comment: I have a problem where a simple table join is taking 75 *seconds* with MAMP Pro, whereas it was taking 120ms using the mysql that was installed with Homebrew

Comment: I have reported this to MAMP community and author but didn't manage to solve that issue that i'm still facing now... :/